# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to post request django rest but this error.I have two Serializer.I want to post a request for full data not via id

```
Exception Value:    
Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict([('title', 'id:2 Смартфон Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra 256GB Black'), ('price', 2019)]).  



 class ShopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        img1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
        img2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
        img3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
        img4 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
        img5 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
        img6 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')
        class Meta:
            model = smartphone
            fields = ("id", "img1", "img2", "img3", "img4", "img5", "img6","title","price","slug")
        def get_image_url(self, obj):
            return obj.image.url
        
        
  class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        smartphone=ShopSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
            model = order
            fields = '__all__'
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            
            smartphone = validated_data.pop('smartphone')
            question = order.objects.create(**validated_data)
            question.smartphone.set(smartphone)
            return question
```

how to solve this problem how to solve this problem how to solve this problem how to solve this problem

views

```
class OrderCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderCreateSerializer
```

Comment: pls add your views.py. Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @MichaelH views added

Comment: views looks good. do you have a sample project on github or can you please provide the models file too?

Comment: @MichaelH https://github.com/mustavfaa/mdsho

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following post request:

```
{
    "smartphone": [{
        "id": 2,
        "img1": "/media/photos/498f6387e90cfee88f98c4379b0d2057ec3623ee_228615_1_qhhauLD.jpg",
        "img2": "/media/photos/aaf2ece82f9b4d357c78c3bac9eb61e4b6a5dc0e_228615_3_K7RDb8Z.jpg",
        "img3": "/media/photos/00d7a263681301aa35d9dad51cf7d0859965bc5c_228615_2_jBLEZqi.jpg",
        "img4": "/media/photos/498f6387e90cfee88f98c4379b0d2057ec3623ee_228615_1_M9GV72N.jpg",
        "img5": "/media/photos/fe49e462ef4847ac6296d4bba6cd4ab35d374daf_228615_5_CgYDohH.jpg",
        "img6": "/media/photos/b036713f6015464a366dbc1890f0b66041015f64_227736_1_1yAxj5T.jpg",
        "price": 2019,

        "slug": "id2-samsung-galaxy-note-20-ultra-256gb-black",
        "title": "id:2 Смартфон Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra 256GB Black"
    }],
    "orderCustomer": 6,
    "orderAddress": 5
}
```

**Update:**

Also make sure that this line works as expected
`question.smartphone.set(smartphone)`.

```py
smartphones = validated_data.pop('smartphone')
smartphone_models = []
for sm in smartphones:
    print("value of sm is: {}".format(sm))
    print("type of sm is: {}".format(type(sm)))
    new_smartphone = smartphone.objects.create(sm)
    new_smartphone.save()
    smartphone_models.append(new_smartphone)
question = order.objects.create(**validated_data)
print(smartphone_models)
question.smartphone.set(smartphone_models)
```

Comment: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'objects' such an error came out

Comment: @AsylkhanMustafa sorry my fault. I updated the answer

Comment: please also notice the addition curly braces in the post request

Comment: create () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given  error

Comment: what's the output if you add `print(sm)` right before this line

Comment: also a error        create () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: yes, but you should see a log message in your console

Comment: `return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: you should be able to see the value of the variable right before the error occurs due to the print command

Comment: if i change `smartphones` to `smartphone` this error throws

               `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'objects'`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "smartphone": [
"id": 2
"img1": "/media/photos/498f6387e90cfee88f98c4379b0d2057ec3623ee_228615_1_qhhauLD.jpg"
"img2": "/media/photos/aaf2ece82f9b4d357c78c3bac9eb61e4b6a5dc0e_228615_3_K7RDb8Z.jpg"
"img3": "/media/photos/00d7a263681301aa35d9dad51cf7d0859965bc5c_228615_2_jBLEZqi.jpg"
"img4": "/media/photos/498f6387e90cfee88f98c4379b0d2057ec3623ee_228615_1_M9GV72N.jpg"
"img5": "/media/photos/fe49e462ef4847ac6296d4bba6cd4ab35d374daf_228615_5_CgYDohH.jpg"
"img6": "/media/photos/b036713f6015464a366dbc1890f0b66041015f64_227736_1_1yAxj5T.jpg"
"price": 2019

"slug": "id2-samsung-galaxy-note-20-ultra-256gb-black"
"title": "id:2 Смартфон Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra 256GB Black"
],
    "orderCustomer": 6,
    "orderAddress": 5
}
```

My post request it looks like this

Comment: why are there no semicolons in the smartphone list?

Comment: @MichaelH yes I forgot there just